# Sum Aggregation ignores negative values

Tags: elasticsearch

I have mapped on elasticsearch a type called `measure`, which contains both sensorId and value as string.

Mapping.

```
{
    "measures": {
        "mappings": {
            "summarizedmeasure": {
                "properties": {
                    "sensorId": {
                        "type": "string"
                    }
                    "timestamp": {
                        "type": "date",
                        "format": "dateOptionalTime"
                    },
                    "value": {
                        "type": "string"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

There are some negative values indexed, but when I calculate Sum Aggregated by Days It's giving positive value.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": 
        {
          "match": {
            "sensorId": "123"
          }
        }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "value_per_day": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "timestamp",
        "interval": "day"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "total": {
          "sum": {
            "script": "Float.parseFloat(doc['value'].value)"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Please help me to solve this issue. Thank you

Comment: Can you give me some sample documents too , with of course negative values too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mapping

```
                "value": {
                    "type": "string"
                }
```

needs to use `index: not_analyzed` or to analyze the value **without** removing the `-` (minus sign). The default analyzer in Elasticsearch - `standard` one - removes some characters and lowercases the string (among others).

For the mapping below, the script works as expected:

```
    "value": {
      "type": "string",
      "index": "not_analyzed"
    }
```

Or, but I think this is even more costly than regular scripting, is to use the `_source` object in your script, since that one contains the original text that was indexed:

`"script": "Float.parseFloat(_source.value)"`

Comment: Is there any way to remove or ignore analyzer without re-mapping my type? The elasticsearch instance is in production environment.

Comment: You can change the mapping on the fly by making the field as a multi-field (look for "Upgrade to a multi-field" in [this blog post](https://www.elastic.co/blog/changing-mapping-with-zero-downtime), BUT the field `value.raw` (`PUT /measures/summarizedmeasure/_mapping
{
  "summarizedmeasure": {
    "properties": {
      "value": {
        "type": "string",
        "fields": {
          "raw": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}`)will only be valid for newly indexed documents.

Comment: If you want to change this for already existent documents you need to re-index them, no other option.

Comment: Or, use `_source` in your script, but I think this will be more costly.

Comment: Ok, for the moment I'm gonna use `_source` and in the near future re-index all data. Thank you.